# When writing to a text document it doesn't give all of the passwords given

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made a Password Generator which gives me passwords by the quantity and length requested, I wanted to make all of the given passwords be saved into a txt document called "Your_Saved_Keys" however only one of the generated passwords are saved not all of them

```
import random
import time

print('''
Password Generator V2.0
=======================
''')

chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!@£$%^&*().,? 
0123456789'

number = input('number of passwords? ')
number = int(number)

length = input('password length? ')
length = int(length)

print('''\nhere are your passwords: ''')

for pwd in range(number):
  password = ''''''
  for c in range(length):
    password += random.choice(chars)
  print(password)

save = input("""Do you want to save it to a txt file? Y/N""")

if save == "Y":
  format = ".txt"
  title = "Your_Saved_Keys"
  text_file = open(title + format, "w")
  text_file.write(password))
  print("Save Successful")

if save == "N":
  print("You Selected No")
print("-----------------------------------")
input("Press enter to exit")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your password variable is being overwritten every time. Only the last password is available in  it. You could just save all passwords to a list and then write it to the file. This code is working

```
import random
import time

print('''
Password Generator V2.0
=======================
''')

chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!@£$%^&*().,?0123456789'

number = input('number of passwords? ')
number = int(number)

length = input('password length? ')
length = int(length)

passwords=[]
print('''\nhere are your passwords: ''')

for pwd in range(number):
  password=""
  for c in range(length):
      password+=random.choice(chars)
  passwords.append(password)
  print(password)

save = input("""Do you want to save it to a txt file? Y/N""")

if save == "Y":
  format = ".txt"
  title = "Your_Saved_Keys"
  with open(title + format, "w") as text_file:
      for password in passwords:
          text_file.write(password+'\n')
  print("Save Successful")

if save == "N":
  print("You Selected No")
print("-----------------------------------")
input("Press enter to exit")
```

Answer (score 1):

You ask for saving and also do the saving after the whole loop over `range(number)` is already done. So of course only the last generated password is saved.

Ask before the loop and save every password within the loop or save all passwords in a list and save the list afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You're writing `password` variable into file. `password` variable in your code stores the last generated password in the loop.

So, to achieve what you want,

Store your generated passwords in a list. (In the first loop, add each generated password in this list)

Then write the content of this list into your file.

Note: I suggest you to apply encryption to your file

Comment: I am planning to do this later